# STRING_AGG with specific criteria

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a dilemma, I'm able to convert the following Sample data:

```
declare @table table
(
    iTermID int
,   cTermDesc1 varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc2 varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc3 varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc4 varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc5 varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc6 varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc7 varchar(30)
)

insert into @table
(
    iTermID
,   cTermDesc1
,   cTermDesc2
,   cTermDesc3
,   cTermDesc4
,   cTermDesc5
,   cTermDesc6
,   cTermDesc7
)
values
    (1,'Current','30 Days','60 Days','90 Days','120 Days','150 Days','180 Days')
,   (3,'Current','30 Days','60 Days','90 Days','120 Days','150 Days','180 Days')
,   (4,'Current','7 Days','14 Days','21 Days','28 Days','35 Days','42 Days')
,   (5,'Current','14 Days','28 Days','42 Days','56 Days','70 Days','84 Days');
```

with this script:

```
with cte as (
select
cTermDesc1+','+cTermDesc2+','+cTermDesc3+','+cTermDesc4+','+cTermDesc5+','+cTermDesc6+','+cTermDesc7    term
from    @table
)
,   data as (
select  distinct
Value
from    cte
outer apply string_split(term,',')
)
,   retur as (
select
Value
,
case Value
when 'Current'  then 1
when '7 Days'   then 2
when '14 Days'  then 3
when '21 Days'  then 4
when '28 Days'  then 5
when '35 Days'  then 6
when '42 Days'  then 7
when '56 Days'  then 8
when '70 Days'  then 9
when '84 Days'  then 10
when '30 Days'  then 11
when '60 Days'  then 12
when '90 Days'  then 13
when '120 Days' then 14
when '150 Days' then 15
when '180 Days' then 16
else 17 end sort
from    data
)

select
string_agg(quotename(Value),',') within group (order by sort desc)
from    retur
```

to look like this (expected results) ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cab17c65eb255c6d01d525d087ec1381)):

```
[180 Days],[150 Days],[120 Days],[90 Days],[60 Days],[30 Days],[84 Days],[70 Days],[56 Days],[42 Days],[35 Days],[28 Days],[21 Days],[14 Days],[7 Days],[Current]
```

[image: Expected Results]

I require to get the same results as my expected results above, but without using a `CASE`.

I tried altering my `CTE` to this:

```
with cte as (
select
'1-'+cTermDesc1+','+'2-'+cTermDesc2+','+'3-'+cTermDesc3+','+'4-'+cTermDesc4+','+'5-'+cTermDesc5+','+'6-'+cTermDesc6+','+'7-'+cTermDesc7 term
from    @table
)
,   data as (
select  distinct
Value
from    cte
outer apply string_split(term,',')
)
,   retur as (
select
    substring(Value,charindex('-',Value,1)+1,20)    Value
,   left(Value,1) sort
from    data
)

select
string_agg(quotename(Value),',') within group (order by sort desc)
from    retur
```

But now I don't get the same order as my expected results above.

Results:

```
[180 Days],[42 Days],[84 Days],[150 Days],[35 Days],[70 Days],[120 Days],[28 Days],[56 Days],[21 Days],[42 Days],[90 Days],[14 Days],[28 Days],[60 Days],[14 Days],[30 Days],[7 Days],[Current]
```

[image: Incorrect Results]

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b461b3686b1f580f2f81d4f19efc746)

Is there maybe an easier way I can achieve this?

**PLEASE NOTE THAT I ONLY NEED ONE "CURRENT" RETURNED**

**EDIT**

Here is my sample data with the Code included:

```
declare @table table
(
    iTermID int
,   Code        varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc1  varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc2  varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc3  varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc4  varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc5  varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc6  varchar(30)
,   cTermDesc7  varchar(30)
)

insert into @table
(
    iTermID
,   Code
,   cTermDesc1
,   cTermDesc2
,   cTermDesc3
,   cTermDesc4
,   cTermDesc5
,   cTermDesc6
,   cTermDesc7
)
values
    (1,'MNTH-INV','Current','30 Days','60 Days','90 Days','120 Days','150 Days','180 Days')
,   (3,'MNTH-STM','Current','30 Days','60 Days','90 Days','120 Days','150 Days','180 Days')
,   (4,'7 Days','Current','7 Days','14 Days','21 Days','28 Days','35 Days','42 Days')
,   (5,'14 Days','Current','14 Days','28 Days','42 Days','56 Days','70 Days','84 Days')
```

Comment: Can you change the database structure a bit?

Comment: Unfortunately not @ZoharPeled, hence I had to work around it...

Comment: Can you explain the logic of this particular order? Initially I thought it was just the number of days descending, but then I say you had 60 days and 30 days before 84 days, so now I'm confused.

Comment: Thank you @ZoharPeled, the reason I require it in that order is due to it having to show like that in a Pivot. (I'm dynamically pivoting the above) So the results I get from this script, is my column names for my dynamic pivot...

Comment: Can you describe the rules that determine the order the values appear in the output? It looks like there are two groups in your source data by `iTermID` - the first group is IDs 1 and 3, which should must be deduplicated and sorted (descending) before the second group, IDs 4 and 5. Does your real data contain more groups? How are they identified?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @EdHarper, my real data looks exactly like my sample data. The only difference is, I excluded the code column which differentiates the rows from each other, i.e. no duplicate rows...

Comment: I don't really care **why** you need this order, I'm more interested to know the **logic** that dictates this order. I mean, why is `180 days` before `150 days` while `60 days` is before `84 days`?

Comment: Why can't `CASE` be used here? Are there any other restrictions on which features of the language can be used in the solution?

Comment: The reason why the the order is like is due to each ageing period (Code) that needs to show in their order first, then only the other can be shown, but because some of the Ageing Terms are duplicated, I needed to remove the duplicates for the Pivot to work (as mentioned in my previous comment). So the remaining columns still need to show in that order. Also notice that each row has `[Current]`, which I'm only showing last, because it should only appear once. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The reason why I don't want a case is because of the fact that the data might not always be the same, which means the case would not work, because it is hard coded - I need my "sort" to be dynamic based on the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a generic version that will always put the values from `MNTH-INV` and `MNTH-STM` in sequence before the values for `7 days` and `14 days`. It gives the correct sequence of values for the inputs in the question.

It's hard to be sure whether this is correct in all circumstances, since the rules for defining the order aren't explicitly given in the question/comments.

(All of the logic here has been written without `CASE` since when I was working on it I hadn't seen the comment that explains why the OP wants to avoid `CASE`)

```
;WITH grpCTE
AS
(
    SELECT  v.grp,
            t.cTermDesc1,t.cTermDesc2,t.cTermDesc3,t.cTermDesc4,t.cTermDesc5,t.cTermDesc6,t.cTermDesc7
    FROM    @table AS t
    JOIN    (VALUES (1,1),(3,1), (4,2), (5,2)) AS v(iTermID, grp)
    ON      v.iTermID = t.iTermID
) 
,valuesCTE
AS
(

    SELECT grp, cTermDesc1 AS dayCount FROM grpCTE
    UNION
    SELECT grp, cTermDesc2 AS dayCount FROM grpCTE
    UNION                              
    SELECT grp, cTermDesc3 AS dayCount FROM grpCTE
    UNION                              
    SELECT grp, cTermDesc4 AS dayCount FROM grpCTE
    UNION                              
    SELECT grp, cTermDesc5 AS dayCount FROM grpCTE
    UNION                              
    SELECT grp, cTermDesc6 AS dayCount FROM grpCTE
    UNION                              
    SELECT grp, cTermDesc7 AS dayCount FROM grpCTE
)
,aggCTE
AS
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(dayCount),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY grp, TRY_CAST(LEFT(dayCount,3) AS INT) desc) AS retur
    FROM    valuesCTE
    WHERE TRY_CAST(LEFT(dayCount,3) AS INT) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT CONCAT(retur, ',[' + v.dayCount + ']') AS retur
FROM aggCTE AS a
OUTER 
APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) dayCount FROM  valuesCTE WHERE dayCount = 'Current') AS v
```